# How to get float values from PostgreSQL table as float only instead of Decimal in psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) for querying [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database.

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

DB_CONNECTION = {
  'host': os.getenv('PG_HOST'),
  'database': os.getenv('PG_DB_NAME'),
  'user': os.getenv('PG_USER'),
  'password': os.getenv('PG_PASSWORD')
}

connection = psycopg2.connect(**DB_CONNECTION)
connection.autocommit = True
cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)

# amount column type is numeric in table
query = 'SELECT userid, amount FROM some_table WHERE userid = %(userid)s'
cursor.execute(query, {'userid': 1234})
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows[0]['amount']) # This is value is object of decimal.Decimal
```

`rows[0]['amount']` is object of `decimal.Decimal` class. Is there any simple and clean way to get this value as `float`? I do not want cast this into float by `float(rows[0]['amount'])` manually.

Comment: What type is amount in postgres?

Comment: @Jeremy: amount's type is numeric

Answer (score 6):

Summary - you can register a custom type conversion function based on the OID of the type returned in the query. The `psycopg2` docs give this exact example:

```
DEC2FLOAT = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
    psycopg2.extensions.DECIMAL.values,
    'DEC2FLOAT',
    lambda value, curs: float(value) if value is not None else None)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(DEC2FLOAT)
```

See -

- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-of-sql-types-into-python-objects
- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#problems-with-type-conversions

You can also cast in the SQL itself - `select userid, amount::float from some_table ...`, but that seems to violate your requirement for avoiding specific casts.